# C++ #define my me ->

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, defined

I am going through the source of an older application.
In this code I see a lot of the usage "my".

It was defined as

```
#define my  me ->
```

But I am unsure what exactely that means. 
Does that mean that if I use "my", it will use "this->"?

I know it is not a good practice, but I need to understand what it does.

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is more info from the author:

```
/*
    Use the macros 'I' and 'thou' for objects in the formal parameter lists
    (if the explicit type cannot be used).
    Use the macros 'iam' and 'thouart'
    as the first declaration in a function definition.
    After this, the object 'me' or 'thee' has the right class (for the compiler),
    so that you can use the macros 'my' and 'thy' to refer to members.
    Example: int Person_getAge (I) { iam (Person); return my age; }
*/
#define I  Any void_me
#define thou  Any void_thee
#define iam(klas)  klas me = (klas) void_me
#define thouart(klas)  klas thee = (klas) void_thee
#define my  me ->
#define thy  thee ->
#define his  him ->
```

But I still cannot see the definition of "me".

Comment: What you have there doesn't define `me`. It defines `my`. (And it's horrible.)

Comment: Whatever it is, I wouldn't bother using it ....

Comment: I bet there's a `#define me this` somewhere else. I'd remove it all (replace the evil macros with the normal code) if you can.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "my", not "me". Post changed accordingly.

Comment: wtf. Do yourself a favor and run the hell away. The author of that code was clinically insane.

Comment: I think the same, but I need to get through the code :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `#define` is very straightforward in this matter: when you use `my` in your code, it will be substituted by `me ->`, so the code like this

```
struct X {
    char first_name[100];
    char last_name[100];
    int age;
} *me;

me = malloc(sizeof(struct X));
strcpy(my first_name, "John");
strcpy(my last_name, "John");
my age = 23;
```

will actually mean

```
strcpy(me->first_name, "John");
strcpy(me->last_name, "John");
me->age = 23;
```

Although this trick may look cute, it is grossly misleading to readers familiar with the syntax of C. I would strongly recommend against using it in your code.

Comment: I added more info in the post, perhaps that makes it more clear.

Comment: @tmighty Wow! I thought this `#define` was strange, but the other `#define`s are just evil!

Comment: There's nothing evil about such things. Using the preprocessor to define a new language on top of the original is perfectly OK and more or less the entirety of what it does. It's baffling when viewed as C, but that's not what it is: it's the author's *custom language based on C*. The preprocessor is a great and convenient tool for playing around in such design spaces.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use `my` you will use `me ->`.

this will gives you an error unless `me` is defined somehow reasonable when `my` is used.

```
class B {
public:
    void f() {}
};


#define my me ->
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    B* b = new B();
    b my f(); // error, expanded to: b me -> f()
    B* me = new B();
    my f(); // OK, expanded to: me -> f()
    delete b;
    delete me;
    return 0;
}
```

but:

```
#define me
#define my me ->
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    B* b = new B();
    b my f(); //  OK, expanded to: b -> f();
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a macro which makes `my` an alias for `me ->`.

The intended use seems to be so to allow usage of `my x` for any member `x` given that `me` is a pointer to some object. Hence, these two will be equivalent given that macro:

```
me->x
my x
```

Most likely, you also have a macro like this, somewhere in the code:

```
#define me this
```

which would let you use `me` instead of `this` in a member function. The intended effect is so that, in any member function of a class with member `x`, these two are equivalent:

```
my x
this->x
```

and it will unambiguously refer to the member `x` of the current instance, even if a local variable with the same name exists - because that's what `this->x` does.

That being said, **this trick is horrible**. It doesn't add anything which isn't already in the language - it only creates a new syntax for something which already has a well-defined and well-known syntax.

Also, by virtue of being a macro, it will very easily break perfectly valid code. For example,As soon as someone tries to declare a variable of type `int` called `my`, this macro could lead to very confusing error messages, as the actual code generated is:

```
// This is what is written:
int my;
// This is what it becomes:
int me ->;
// Unless the #define for me is available, in which case you get:
int this ->
```

My tip, and it seems from other comments as if there's a strong consensus: **Avoid this macro and, if possible, delete it and replace all its uses by an ordinary member access**.

The only reason I could think of to have such a macro would be in a translation layer for some other language in which `me` actually means the same as `this` in C++ and `my` is the same as `this ->`. So unless this is part of some lightweight language translation layer used on top of a C++ compiler, it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will replace instances of "my" with "me ->" when it compiles.

So presumably the intent is to dereference a pointer called "me". i.e. if the object pointed to has a method Dog(), instead of

```
me->Dog()
```

you can just use

```
my Dog()
```